# sudoku algorithm analysis

Tags: code-analysis, sudoku, big-o

This is the code for solving sudoku (9x9):

```
#include <iostream>
#define dim 9
#define br_polja dim*dim

using namespace std;


bool Fsearch (int tab[dim][dim],int *x,int *y, int cand[dim], int *num_cand, int &free) {
int min=9; 
*x=-1;
*y=-1;
free=0;
for (int i=0;i<dim;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<dim;j++) {

        if (tab[i][j]!=0) continue;
        free+=1;
        *num_cand=0;
        int cand_f[dim];
        for (int w=0;w<dim;w++)
            cand_f[w]=1;  

        int p,q; 
        p=i+3-(i%3); 
        q=j+3-(j%3);

        for (int w=p-3;w<p;w++) 
            for (int r=q-3;r<q;r++)
                if (tab[w][r]!=0){        
                                   cand_f[tab[w][r]-1]=0;
                                   }

        for (int w=0;w<dim;w++) { 
            if (tab[w][j]!=0) cand_f[tab[w][j]-1]=0; 
            if (tab[i][w]!=0) cand_f[tab[i][w]-1]=0;
            }

        for (int w=0;w<dim;w++)
            if (cand_f[w]!=0) 
               *num_cand+=1;


        if (*num_cand==1) { 
                                   *x=i;
                                   *y=j;
                                   int z=0;
                                   for (int w=0;w<dim;w++)
                                       if (cand_f[w]!=0) { 
                                          cand[z]=w+1;
                                          z++;
                                          }
                                   return true;
                                   }
        else if (*num_cand<min && *num_cand>0) {
                                     int z=0;
                                     for (int w=0;w<dim;w++)
                                         if (cand_f[w]!=0) { 
                                            cand[z]=w+1;
                                            z++;
                                            }
                                     min=*num_cand;
                                     *x=i;
                                     *y=j;
                                     }
        else if (*num_cand==0) {
             return false;
             }
        } 
    } 

    *num_cand=min;
    if (free<1) return false;
    else return true;           
}

bool Fsudoku(int tab[dim][dim]) {
 int free=0;

 int x,y;
 int cand[dim];
 int num_cand;
 brojacK=0;
 if (!Fsearch(tab,&x,&y,cand, &num_cand,free)) {
                                               if (free==0) return true;
                                               else return false;
                                               }


 for (int i=0;i<num_cand;i++) {
     tab[x][y]=cand[i];
     if (Fsudoku(tab)) return true;
     else tab[x][y]=0;
     }
 return false;

 }
```

Can someone tell help me classify this algorithm in Big O or Big Theta notation. I got O(n^3) but as we can see that's not true! So, give me a tip or an advice how to start, I would be very thankful.
And if you like, I can post this in pseudo-code too!

Thanks,
MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big O is about which terms dominate.

So how many times do each of the loops run?

Are they of fixed length, or do they vary?

What parameters can change that would effect the run time?

Comment: Normally I would have posted this answer as a comment, but the OP asked for tips :-)